# Access website over local network from other devices?

Tags: networking, web-applications

I have a website that I'm running locally at `localhost:8000`. I'd like to access my site from other devices on my network. I've tried to visit the site via my computer's internal IP address via: `127.0.0.1:8000`but this doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Three most probable things:

- Check if there is a network route between the client and the server machine (commands like `PING` and `TRACERT` will help);
- Check if the server machine has a **firewall**. If it does, there must be a rule allowing (opening) connections through that port (8000) in TCP;

Most likely, the problem is one of the two above. If not, there's one last thing:

- Make sure the web server (the one that serves `localhost:8000`) is bound to listen to all IP addresses (not only 127.0.0.1).

To know that, search for ***servername bind all ip addresses*** on google. E.g., for apache HTTPD, it'd be *[apache bind all ip addresses](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20bind%20all%20ip%20adresses)*.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I do in similar cases:

- search `rejetto hfs` on google, it is single executable less than 1Mb size and download it into your server machine.
- after starting it, follow  menu->IP addresses. these are all your possible addresess on the server side.
- these are your IP addresses to enter, and your port is 8000 as you mentioned.

most possible IP addresses you will find are in the format of following:

- 192.168.?.?
- 10.0.0.?
- 169.254.?.?

besided you will probably need to add a firewall rule for your server app.